# Error While Renaming Column in PostgreSQL View

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science

I'm facing an issue with altering the column name in a view using PostgreSQL.
My attempt with the query

```sql
create or replace view order_summary as
select o.ord_id, o.date, p.prod_name, c.cust_name
, (p.price * o.quantity) - ((p.price * o.quantity) * disc_percent::float/100) as cost
, c.cust_id
from tb_customer_table c
join tb_order_details o on o.cust_id = c.cust_id
join tb_product_info p on p.prod_id = o.prod_id;
```

```sql
ALTER VIEW order_summary RENAME COLUMN prod_name TO Product_Name
```

resulted in an error:

```sql
ERROR: syntax error at or near "COLUMN" 
LINE 1: ALTER VIEW order_summary RENAME column prod_name TO Product_Name.
```

Could someone kindly assist me in understanding the correct approach to rename a column in a view in PostgreSQL? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The syntax seems correct and it works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UrccSMyd). Are you using an older PostgreSQL  version which does not support alter view  rename column .. syntax ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-alterview.html

Comment: that was only supported with Postgres 13 and above, you need to replace the view with my code below